# ValueError while using scipy.integrate to calculate value of a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am trying to evaluate a function for different values of a variable `n`, I created a np.linspace for this vairiable and plugged it into a function `Q`:

```
def Q(z_i, z_min,f_gamma, mDM, sigma_v,n, with_ucmh):
    dQdz_z = lambda z : dQdz(f_gamma, mDM, sigma_v, z,n, with_ucmh)
    integrand = lambda z: ((1/((1+z)*H_z(z)))* (dQdz_z(z)) * np.exp(-tau(z)))
    second_part = const.C*const.B*integrate.romberg(integrand,z_min,z_i)
    return second_part

z_i = 2.0e6
z_min = 5.0e4
sigma_v = 3.0e-27 
f_gamma = 1.
mDM = 10. 
with_ucmh = True
n = np.linspace(1.,1.3,100)
mu = Q(z_i, z_min,f_gamma, mDM, sigma_v,n, with_ucmh)
```

I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence` that point me to the line where I use the integrate.romberg method of scipy, but I don't understand how come I get here this sort of error..

Comment: Do you have the definition of `dQdz(...)`?

Comment: Check that `dQdz` returns a scalar when `z` is a scalar.  One way to get that error is for the integrand to return an array with size larger than 1. E.g. `romberg(lambda x: np.array([1,-1]), 0, 1)`.

Comment: Your `n` is an array with length 100.  Does `dQdz` return an array with the same shape as its `n` argument?  If so, you'll have to deal with that in `Q`, perhaps with a loop over `n`.

Comment: I tried right away the approach of looping over n, it does the job, I will go and check what dQdz is giving me..